# Set CHECK constraint on table when using nhibernate mapping-by-code

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How do I set a check constraint on a table when mapping by code in NHibernate 3.3?

i.e. the code equivalent for the following hbm:

```
<class name="myclass" table="mytable" check="(col1 = col2 AND col2 > col3)">
 ... columns ...
</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the constraint script to the NH configuration as an auxiliary database object seems to work, although not the cleanest of solutions..

```
config.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new SimpleAuxiliaryDatabaseObject("ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint CHECK (col1 = col2 AND col2 > col3)",
            "ALTER TABLE mytable DROP CONSTRAINT myconstraint"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `"check"` attribute cannot be set by `mapping-by-code` in NHibernate 3.3

Answer (score 0):

Singular table check support has been added in NHibernate 4.0.0-Alpha2; column check likely before that but I am not sure when.

Assuming you have this declaration:

```
var mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();
```

Column check can be added like this:

```
mapper.Class<EntityType>(en => {
  en.Property(x => x.Name, pm => {
    pm.Column(c => c.Check("Name > ''''"));
  })
}
```

Class check unfortunately cannot be added in class mapping for some reason. In addtion, only one check is supported. If multiple checks are specified the last one wins. This can be worked around by AND-chaining the checks into one. A full  workaround is like this:

```
mapper.BeforeMapClass += (inspect, member, custom) => {
  if (member.GetType() == typeof(EntityType)) {
    custom.Check("Name > '''' AND Creator > ''''");
  }
}
```